# elasticsearch 2.4 java 1.7 error connection NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: java, elasticsearch-2.4

I want to create a connection with elasticsearch in order to exectue a query

this is my exception déc. 28, 2017 10:06:11 AM

```
org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService <init>
INFOS: [Shockwave] modules [], plugins [], sites []

Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:288)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:86)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:56)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:64)
at com.intelcom.boot.App.<init>(App.java:59)
at com.intelcom.boot.App.main(App.java:71)
```

this is my main code

```
TransportClient client ;
        InetSocketTransportAddress node = new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300);

        Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                .build();
            client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();
        SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch("index")
                .setTypes("index_type")
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_all", "Rabat")));

        System.out.println(builder);
        SearchResponse response = builder.get(); //<<<==== error
```

thanks for helping

Comment: node is never used....

Comment: how can I add it ?? (thanks youu sos much )

Answer (score 1):

your initialization of es transport client is wrong:

Here is an simple example of initialization:

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
    .put("cluster.name", "myClusterName").build();
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));
```

more refer to [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html)